# Immersions of vector bundles

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $k$ over a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $m$.  Then $E$ can be thought of as a $(m+k)$-dimensional manifold, so the (weak) Whitney immersion theorem states that $E$ can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{2(m+k)}$.

> Is it possible to immerse $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2m + k}$?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what’s our thought behind this question? Why $2m+k$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton If $E$ is trivial, i.e., $E \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^k$, then using the Whitney immersion theorem on $M$ shows that $E$ immerses in $\mathbb{R}^{2m} \times \mathbb{R}^k \cong \mathbb{R}^{2m + k}$.  On the other hand, a first example of a nontrivial bundle is the Mobius line bundle on the circle.  But that too immerses (in fact embeds) in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \cdot 1 + 1} = \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Great question. My gut says that this is very hard to answer.

Comment: The naive approach would be to fix an immersion into $\Bbb R^{2m}$, and then extend the immersion by finding $E$ as a subbundle (equivalently, summand) of $NM \oplus \Bbb R^k$. I believe that over an $m$-manifold, one can find a rank $m$ vector bundle $F$ so that $E \oplus F$ is trivial. So as long as $NM$ is trivial, your answer should be "Yes!" as its rank is $m$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Do you have a reference for the assertion that given a vector bundle $E$ on a $m$-manifold, there exists a rank $m$ bundle $F$ such that $E \oplus F$ is trivial?  If the statement can be modified to "there exists a rank $m$ bundle $F$ such that $E \oplus F \cong NM \oplus \mathbb{R}^k$", then the assumption that $M$ is parallelizable can be dropped.

Comment: @JHF It is a vague recollection. I need to check to make sure it's true. It could be terribly wrong. I'll write something about this when I get a chance (maybe tonight or tomorrow). As of right now I think I might have been wrong and instead "rank $m$ bundle" should be replaced by "rank $mk$ bundle", which is terribly useless for us.
As a word of warning, I did not assume that $M$ is parallelizable --- that does not imply that $NM$ is trivial, nor is the converse true.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an argument filling in the sketch provided by @MikeMiller in the comments.

Fix an immersion $M \looparrowright \mathbb{R}^{2m}$ with normal bundle $\nu_M$, which exists by the weak Whitney immersion theorem.  It suffices to show that there is a bundle monomorphism $E \hookrightarrow \nu_M \oplus \mathbb{R}^k$.  The tubular neighborhood theorem asserts that there is a diffeomorphism of $\nu_M$ onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$, and so this gives an immersion of $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^{2m} \times \mathbb{R}^k \cong \mathbb{R}^{2m + k}$.

It remains to show that such a bundle monomorphism exists.  This follows from the more general proposition.

> **Proposition**.  Given a bundle $E$ of rank $k$ and a bundle $G$ of rank $k + m$ on a $m$-manifold $M$, there exists a bundle $F$ of rank $m$ such that $E \oplus F \cong G$.

The proof of this proposition proceeds by obstruction theory.  The given bundles $E$ and $G$ furnish a classifying map $M \to BO(k) \times BO(k+m)$.  In terms of classifying maps, the conclusion of the proposition is equivalent to showing that the map $M \to BO(k) \times BO(k+m)$ lifts to $BO(k) \times BO(m)$:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. BO(k) \times BO(m) \\
{} @V{1 \times \mu}VV \\ 
M @>>> BO(k) \times BO(k+m)
\end{CD}$$

Note that the cofiber of the vertical map has no positive-dimensional cells in dimensions $\leq m$, while $M$ can be approximated by a $m$-dimensional cell complex.  So the map from $M$ to the cofiber is null, and hence a lift exists.

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad this actually worked out. I got worried and started trying to find counterexamples before I moved on. Of course, I found none.